# Why does my postfix program in Python not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, postfix-mta

I have this code to calculate something given in postfix notation:

```
operator = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^"]
operand=[]
exp=input("Please enter something in postfix notation:")
expression = exp.split(' ')
for ele in expression:
        if(ele not in operator):
            operand.append(ele)
        else:
            number1=eval(operand.pop())
            number2=eval(operand.pop())
        if(ele=="+"):
            answer=number2+number1
        elif(ele=="-"):
            answer=number2-number1
        elif(ele=="*"):
            answer=number2*number1
        elif(ele=="/"):
            answer=number2/number1
        elif(ele=="^"):
            answer=number2**number1
        operand.append(str(answer))
print("answer =", operand[0])
```

I can enter something to calculate but then it says NameError: name 'answer' is not defined and refers to the operand.append(str(answer)) line. How do I fix that and is the rest fine?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.  The long chain of `if`/`elif` that is testing `ele` gets executed even if `ele` wasn't an operator, in which case none of the conditions are true (and nothing gets assigned to `answer).

Comment: If you paste you code into [link](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) you can visualize execution line-by-line and see why the logic is flawed and falls through to the `operand.append(str(answer))`. This approach is very useful for debugging such small programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation isn't correct in your else block, which is appending garbage value for the answer at every element.

```
operator = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^"]
operand=[]
exp=input("Please enter something in postfix notation:")
expression = exp.split(' ')

for ele in expression:
        if(ele not in operator):
            operand.append(ele)
        else:
            number1=eval(operand.pop())
            number2=eval(operand.pop())
            if(ele=="+"):
                answer=number2+number1
            elif(ele=="-"):
                answer=number2-number1
            elif(ele=="*"):
                answer=number2*number1
            elif(ele=="/"):
                answer=number2/number1
            elif(ele=="^"):
                answer=number2**number1
            operand.append(str(answer))

print("answer =", operand[0])
```

Here's your updated code.

Following is the output:

```
Please enter something in postfix notation:15 5 +
answer = 20
```